# Prevent duplicate Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

I have links that when clicked loads the url as a tab in jquery. But when a tab already exist in the tab panel and the link is clicked a second time, i want the already added tab to be selected instead of adding a new tab of the same url.
thanks

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:-

1. `OnClick` of the tab, check if the tab `id` is already exists
2. If `id` is exists then add attribute as selected.